# How to loop through array and check array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

so I have an Array and I want to loop through the Array and check if the values in it match some strings and if so do something.

This is what I have so far:

```
var rgt_count = a_related_genres_leon.length; // <- 3 items

for (var i = 0; i < rgt_count; i++) {

    if inArray("Music", a_related_genres_leon) {
        console.log('Music');
    } else if inArray("TV", a_related_genres_leon) {
        console.log('TV');
    } else if inArray("Comedy", a_related_genres_leon) {
        console.log('Comedy');
    }
}
```

I'm getting a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( error right now.

I also tried this

```
if text($.inArray("Music", a_related_genres_leon)) {
        console.log('Music');
    } else if text($.inArray("TV", a_related_genres_leon)) {
        console.log('TV');
    } else if text($.inArray("Comedy", a_related_genres_leon)) {
        console.log('Comedy');
    }
```

Comment: Syntax error because syntax of `if` clause is different in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either search for a particular element in the array:

```
if ($.inArray("Music", a_related_genres_leon) > -1) {
    console.log('Music');
}
if ($.inArray("TV", a_related_genres_leon) > -1) {
    console.log('TV');
}
if ($.inArray("Comedy", a_related_genres_leon) > -1) {
    console.log('Comedy');
}
```

or iterate over all elements in the array

```
var rgt_count = a_related_genres_leon.length; // <- 3 items
for (var i = 0; i < rgt_count; i++) {
    console.log(a_related_genres_leon[i]);
}
```

but do not do a mixture of both.

Comment: Thanks! So fast, 8 more mins before I can check this, I also just found out that 'if (jQuery.inArray("Music", a_related_genres_leon)) {' works too :)

Comment: @Leon: `inArray` returns the index of the element though, so if the element is at index `0`, the condition will evaluate to `false`, which is wrong. You have to explicitly check that the return value is not `-1` (which means the element is not contained in the array).

Answer (score 2):

Refer this for correct syntax and usage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

```
if($.inArray("Music", a_related_genres_leon) > -1) {
    console.log('Music');
} else if($.inArray("TV", a_related_genres_leon) > -1) {
    console.log('TV');
} else if($.inArray("Comedy", a_related_genres_leon) > -1) {
    console.log('Comedy');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($.inArray("Music", a_related_genres_leon) > -1) {
    console.log('Music');
} else if ($.inArray("TV", a_related_genres_leon) > -1) {
    console.log('TV');
} else if ($.inArray("Comedy", a_related_genres_leon) > -1) {
    console.log('Comedy');
}
```

---

[**From the jQuery.inArray() API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

> The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf()
>   method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the
>   first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.
>
> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 ==
>   false, but 0 !== false), if we're checking for the presence of value
>   within array, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than)
>   -1.

---